# Android Studio error when adding external library

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to implement the Solver SDK in Android Studio. I successfully added it and am able to call functions and instantiate classes from the .jar file but when running I get the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving, PID: 23012
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libSolverSDK.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:972)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1567)
        at SolverPlatform.Problem.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving.MainActivity.Evaluate(MainActivity.java:472)
        at com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving.MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$3(MainActivity.java:202)
        at com.company.vince.physicswhiledriving.-$$Lambda$MainActivity$_ZIHQnNzIub2iCs97DsuIwkLxLQ.onClick(lambda)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1534)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1424)
```

This error is exclusive to Android Studio though, because I'm able to import the .jar file and execute code without error in Eclipse. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you add that in your Android Studio?

Comment: @GenoChen Dragged the .jar file into /app/lib/ and added  
`implementation files(/lib/SolverSDK.jar)` to build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Place `.jar` file and `.so` files in correct folders like the following:

```
project/
├──libs/
|  └── *.jar       <-- if your library has jar files, they go here
├──src/
   └── main/
       ├── AndroidManifest.xml
       ├── java/
       └── jniLibs/ 
           ├── arm64-v8a/                       <-- ARM 64bit
           │   └── yourlib.so
           ├── armeabi-v7a/                     <-- ARM 32bit
           │   └── yourlib.so
           └── x86/                             <-- Intel 32bit
               └── yourlib.so
```

And add below line in the module Gradle file:

```
implementation files('libs/your jar file.jar')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to add "libSolverSDK.so" to the "jniLibs" folder ;)